# SKStoreProductViewController not showing up in swift (in-app purchases)

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, in-app-purchase, viewcontroller

I am trying to add in-app purchases to my iOS app. I followed a tutorial and I created the following code:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

let secondViewController: SKStoreProductViewController = SKStoreProductViewController();

class GameViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate, SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate{   

func buycoin(){
  println("buycoin")
    secondViewController.delegate = self
    var someitunesid:String = "coin200a"
    var productparameters = [SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier: someitunesid]
    secondViewController.loadProductWithParameters(productparameters, {
        (success:Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if success == true{
        self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            println("succes")
    }
        else{
            NSLog("%@", error)
            println("nosucces")
        }

    })
}

func productViewControllerDidFinish(viewController: SKStoreProductViewController!) {
    secondViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

This code works fine. When the function `buycoin()` activates, I only get printed `buycoin` in the console, nothing else.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to put `let secondViewController: SKStoreProductViewController = SKStoreProductViewController();` in the method buy coin itself

Comment: did you sort this?